# Переключатель цветов

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять как правильно решить задание. Есть массив цветов в hex-формате и кнопки Start и Stop
 Нужно написать скрипт, который после нажатия кнопки Start, раз в секунду меняет цвет фона body на случайное значение из массива используя инлайн-стиль. При нажатии на кнопку Stop, изменение цвета фона должно останавливаться.Для генерации случайного числа (индекс элемента массива цветов), нужно использовать  функцию randomIntegerFromInterval. Вот что у меня получилось:

```js
const refs={
   startBtn: document.querySelector('button[data-action="start"'),
  stopBtn: document.querySelector('button[data-action="stop"'),
}
const colors = [
  '#FFFFFF',
  '#2196F3',
  '#4CAF50',
  '#FF9800',
  '#009688',
  '#795548',
];

const randomIntegerFromInterval = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

setInterval('colors()',1000)
```

```html
<button type="button" data-action="start">Start</button>
<button type="button" data-action="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: вы начните делать для начала. создайте страницу. добавьте две кнопки. добавьте массив цветов. создайте упомянутую функцию. Далее загуглите как выполнять действия по таймеру, и найдите там про `setInterval`, потому также прочтите про `clearInterval` для остановки таймера. уже после этого можете посмотреть, как с помощью js задать стиль элементу. А вот когда что-то не будет получаться, напишите тут вопрос.

Comment: В чем вопрос сейчас?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const refs = {
    startBtn: document.querySelector('button[data-action="start"'),
    stopBtn: document.querySelector('button[data-action="stop"'),
  },
  colors = [
    '#FFFFFF',
    '#2196F3',
    '#4CAF50',
    '#FF9800',
    '#009688',
    '#795548',
  ],
  randomIntegerFromInterval = (max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
  },
  setRandomColor = () => {
    const _color = colors[randomIntegerFromInterval(colors.length - 1)]
    console.log(_color)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = _color
  }

let interval = undefined

refs.startBtn.addEventListener('click', e => interval = interval ?
  interval :
  setInterval(() => setRandomColor(), 1000))

refs.stopBtn.addEventListener('click', e => clearInterval(interval))
```

```html
<button type="button" data-action="start">Start</button>
<button type="button" data-action="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @zarina если ответ помог, прошу отметить его галкой (возле голосов)

Comment: я отметила)))))

Comment: @zarina галка так-то не появилась, но ладно, раз отметили так отметили )

Comment: мой рейтинг не позволяет этого сделать(((

Comment: я уже ставила несколько раз и никак(

Comment: нужно чтобы рейтинг был не меня 15 а у меня 1

Comment: Уже отблагодарила!

Answer (score -1):

```
const colors = [
  '#FFFFFF',
  '#2196F3',
  '#4CAF50',
  '#FF9800',
  '#009688',
  '#795548',
];
const refs = {
  bodyColor: document.querySelector('body'),
  startButton: document.querySelector('.start'),
  stopButton: document.querySelector('.stop'),
};
refs.startButton.addEventListener('click', start);
refs.stopButton.addEventListener('click', stop);
const randomIntegerFromInterval = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};
function changeBackground(color) {
  refs.bodyColor.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
let intervalColorChange = undefined;
function start() {
  intervalColorChange = setInterval(randomNumber => {
    randomNumber = randomIntegerFromInterval(0, 5);
    changeBackground(colors[randomNumber]);
  }, 1000);
  refs.stopButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  refs.startButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
function stop() {
  clearInterval(intervalColorChange);
  refs.startButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  refs.stopButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]